# Ubuntu desktop isn't opening after attempted log in

Tags: login, desktop-environments, 17.04

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3evkCZj3FFxQ0p1d0JERW9QWVk) is a link to the video showing what is happening. I took it with my phone so I apologise for the low quality.

When I turn on my laptop, I enter my password to set up the drive, the log in screen pulls up, I enter my password, the screen goes black, and the next screen that appears is the log in screen. I enter my password again, press enter, the same thing happens.

When I type, in the terminal,

```
ls -al .*thority
pwd
```

The output is, first,

```
-rw------- 1 amolith amolith 14000 Jun 19 11:21 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 amolith amolith    59 Jun 19 14:19 .Xauthority
```

Then

```
/home/amolith
```

When I run the command `ls -al` in the `home` directory, the following is the output.

```
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root     4096 Jun  3 11:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root    root     4096 Jun  8 09:30 ..
drwr------ 41 amolith amolith 12288 Jun 19 14:19 amolith
drwxrwxr-x  3 root    root     4096 Jun  3 11:28 .encryptfs
```

When the command `df` is run,

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                           932664        0   9326764   0% /dev
tempfs                         191324     6164    185160   4% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  12831848 12234968         0 100% /
tmpfs                          956604       12    956592   1% /dev.shm
tmpfs                            5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                          956604        0    956604   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loopo                      81408    81408         0 100% /snap/core/1689
/dev/loop1                     366336   366336         0 100% /snap/libreoffice/19
/dev/loop2                     187008   187008         0 100% /snap/atom/8
/dev/loop3                     187008   187008         0 100% /snap/atom/9
/dev/sda1                      474712   123440    322242  28% /boot
tmpfs                          191320        8    191312   1% /run/user/112
tmpfs                          191320        0    191320   0% /run/user/1000
/home/amolith/.Private       12831848 12831848         0 100% /home/amolith
```

When I log in as root:

```
Error found when loading /root/.profile:
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

When I enter `ls -alt | more -7

```
total 133596
-rw-------  1 amolith amolith   18585 Jun 20 13:19 .bash_history
drwxr-xr-x 41 amolith amolith   12288 Jun 20 13:03 .
-rw-------  1 amolith amolith      59 Jun 20 13:03 .Xauthority
drwxr-xr-x 38 amolith amolith   12288 Jun 20 09:17 .cache
drwx------  3 amolith amolith    4096 Jun 19 14:16 .gnupg
```

When I run `grep mesg .profile`:

```
mesg n || true
```

When I run `ls -l / | more`
[image]

`dpkg -l *nvidia*` outputs:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hole
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name          Version    Architecture Description
++-==============-==========-============-=================================================
un nvidia-common  <none>     <none>       (no description available)
un nvidia-legacy- <none>     <none>       (no description available)
un nvidia-prime   <none>     <none>       (no description available)
un nvidia-vdpau-d <none>     <none>       (no description available)
```

I'm very new to Ubuntu; I started using it from ChromeOS a week and a half ago so everything is very foreign and new to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60884/discussion-on-question-by-amolith-ubuntu-desktop-isnt-opening-after-attempted-l).

Answer (score 1):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

**Step #1:** (re-edit with new addition, then reboot)

```
sudo pico /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

[LightDM]
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login=true
allow-guest=true
[XDMCPServer]
[VNCServer]
```

**Step #2:**

- login into text terminal as your normal user
- type `ls -al .*thority*`
- you should see at least two .old files, maybe more if they got recreated
- if you only see two .old files

  - `mv .ICEauthority.old .ICEauthority`
  - `mv .Xauthority.old .Xauthority`

**Step #3:**

- type `ls -alt | more -7` and show me the first five lines (copy/paste into your question, not in comments, please)

**Step #4:**

- type `sudo passwd root`
- enter your admin password
- enter new password for root twice
- type `exit`, then control-alt-f7 to return to normal login screen
- try and log into root with new password

**Step #5:**

- at the normal login screen, use up/down arrows and see if guest appears, and if you can log into guest

**Step #6:**

- in the root account
- start a `terminal` from the dash
- edit .profile

  - `pico .profile` or `gedit .profile`
- change `mesg n || true` to `tty -s && mesg n || true`
- save file and quit pico/gedit
- log out, log back into root and confirm no errors

Comment: The first five lines scroll up too far for me to see them.

Comment: You lost me? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: I got a notification about a comment/message you just sent me but I can't find it. The first five lines are too high to show on my screen. There are over 48 lines.

Comment: I updated my answer, and did a minor edit in lightdm.conf to enable guest. Go ahead and do all of the steps and report back.

Comment: I just added `allow-guest=true` to lightdm.conf, and reboot.

Comment: I cannot show the first five lines of step 3 because there are more lines than can show on my screen. I've done all the rest though.

Comment: can you log into root or guest now? let me edit step #3 so you can do it.

Comment: I did it. I can log in as root but there's an error. It's in the question above the results of Step #3.

Comment: Good! You can get into root with a full desktop, yes? Start `terminal` from the dash and type `grep mesg .profile` and show me. Also, have you tried logging into guest? And ok, repeat step #3 with `more -15`.

Comment: I added it. Logging in as guest does the same thing as logging in as user.

Comment: Ah! Do Step #6 to fix the root login error. And to confirm... you can successfully log into root and get the desktop, but with your user account or the guest account, they both log you out again, correct?

Comment: You are correct. I have to go and when I get back home, I'll have to do homework then I'm going to play my double bass at this BBQ place so I'll have to do the rest probably tomorrow after school. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: OK, when you get back tomorrow, do a `ls -l / | more` and edit the result into your question, a screenfull at a time. Then ping me.

Comment: I did step 6 and there are no errors when I log in as root. I also added the output from ls -l to the question.

Comment: OK, just to reconfirm... you can log into root and get the normal full desktop, but not into your account or guest? Do you have a nvidia video card? If so, `dpkg -l *nvidia*`.

Comment: [These](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-chromebook-c710-2856-11-6-celeron-847-chrome-os-2-gb-ram-16-gb-ssd/specs/) are the specs for my computer. I added the output from `dpkg -l *nvidia*`.

Comment: I guess that it's time to reinstall. I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Is there a way I can see a list of installed applications so I can reinstall them when u reinstall Ubuntu? Also, would you recommend 16.04 or 17.04? I was using 17.04 first but I know that 16.04 is . . . stable? I guess would be the term?

Comment: Log into the root account. The best that I can do to get you a (longish) list of all software installed is in terminal to do `dpkg -l | grep ii | grep -v lib* > software.txt`. Then print `software.txt`. When you reinstall, make sure to **uncheck** the format box so it'll keep your /home directory intact. I'd go with Ubuntu GNOME 17.04  version, since in 17.10 that'll be the default any way.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. If there's anything I can do for you by way of thank you, please let me know.

Comment: If you like, vote up my answer (not accept) even though the story isn't over yet :-) Thanks. Let me know how it all works out.